# opencv imshow() didnt work on windows 10,but works on mac why?

Tags: opencv, imshow, python

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('lena.jpg',1)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cv2.waitKey(1)
```

No image is displayed while running the program above on windows10 (python 3.10,pycharm editor),
but this same code worked on macbook pro.
How to run this on windows ?

Comment: Are you sure the file `lena.jpg` exists in your current folder on Windows ? You can try to use a full path if you are not sure. You should also put a breakpoint and check if `img` is properly read.

Comment: Try `print(img.shape)` after loading it to be sure it is non-null and the dimensions you expect.

Comment: @wohlstad the file exists in the same folder .I also tried the full path ,but no image .

Comment: iam receiving another warnings - Cannot find reference 'xxx' in __init__.py

Comment: for example,Cannot find reference 'line' in '__init__.py'    " cannot find waitKey() in init.py"  "cannot find destroyAllWindows() in init.py"

Comment: @MarkSetchell i tried,but error

Comment: Check you didn't name your script `cv2.py` which would clash with **OpenCV** itself.

Comment: i install opencv-python-contrib its worked to some codes,but in case of setMouseCallback() its not worked.Cannot find reference 'setMouseCallback' in '__init__.pyi'  @MarkSetchell